# Verifying consistency of strict and non-strict partial orders constraints

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-algorithms, ds.data-structures, partial-order

I am building a set of constraints of the kind $x < y$ and $x \leq y$, where $<$ is a strict order and $\leq$ is a non-strict order on the same set, and $x$ and $y$ are abstract variables representing elements of the set.  The laws that relate the two orderings are the same as $<$ and $\leq$ for integers.  I need to make sure that each constraint that I add does not make the set inconsistent (e.g. adding $x < y$ and then $y < x$ I'd get an error).

Now, if I had only the $<$ constraints I could get away with generating a graph and then doing a topological sort, or with disjoint-sets.  The problem is that I'm not sure how to handle the additional $\leq$ constraints.

One idea is to express $x \leq y$ as $\neg (x > y)$, and to keep two graphs:  one for the actual $<$ relations and one for the negated ones.  Then we'd need to check, at each new constraints, whether there are overlapping paths between the two graphs, in which case we'd have a problem.  However this seems rather costly since it seems to me that we'd need to analyze all the pairs each time.

Another idea would be to 'collapse' $\leq$ relations to equalities or $<$ when needed, but again I'm quite uncertain on the details.

Is this problem described somewhere?  As a bonus, I'd like the data structures involved to be purely functional.

Comment: If your graph has one type of edge for < and another type for $\le$, then I think an inconsistency is equivalent to a cycle that contains at least one edge of the first type.

Comment: That sounds plausible, I'll think about it!  If that's correct, is there a nice way to treat those 'hybrid' graphs?

Comment: Although detecting cycles and then checking if they contain a 'strict' edge is probably good enough...

Comment: If your order is really order, then a constraint $x\le y$ is either equivalent to the constraint $x< y$ (if $x$ and $y$ are distinct elements) or redundant (if $x$ is $y$).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with 'redundant', consider the case where you add $x \leq y$, $y \leq x$, $x < z$, $z < y$.  You need the first two constraints to detect the inconsistency later.

Comment: Redundant means redundant: by definition, $x\le x$ for every $x$, hence adding such a constraint does not change anything. As for the rest, a part of the definition of order is that $x\le y$ and $y\le x$ can only happen if $x=y$. So, if $x$ and $y$ are distinct objects, then $x\le y,y\le x$ is already inconsistent. If you are actually talking about preorders instead of orders, you should say so.

Comment: I still don't get how you are proposing to solve the problem.  Obviously if $x \leq y$ and $y \leq x$ then I can derive $x = y$, which is basically what I suggest when I say 'Another idea would be to...'.  The problem is that you don't have any information about the variables themselves so you need to be careful to convert the $\leq$ constraint to an equality or a $<$ when you have the right constraints to do so.

Comment: As far as terminology goes, I'm not sure what you mean by 'order', but treat $<$ and $\leq$ as you'd treat the respective relations on the integers.  They're both total orders (although the totality doesn't really matter here), one irreflexive (strict), one reflexive (non-strict).

Comment: I probably do not understand the setup. Are you saying that two different variables can represent the same object, but you cannot test them for equality? Then a single constraint $x< y$ may be inconsistent (if $x$ and $y$ represent the same object) and you cannot detect this.

Comment: The variables don't 'represent' anything concrete initially.  I only need to derive _some_ ordering from the constraints that I have.

Comment: My intuition is that Tyson is correct, and that it suffices to detect cycles with at least a single $<$ in it. My intuition is also that you may "collapse" nodes connected with a $\leq$, as the new graph is satisfiable iff the old graph is. There are a number of efficient cycle detection algorithms.

Comment: OK, so the best strategy would be to keep the graph free of $\leq$ cycles by collapsing them, so that if there is a cycle at all after the collapsing step it must be one with a $<$ in it.  I know about efficient cycle detection, but it's the rest of the algorithm (in this case collapsing the cycles) which I'd like to write in a nice way.

Comment: You are describing a structure with three relations $x\le y$, $x < y$, and $x=y$.  When $x < y$ then also $x \le y$, and when $x=y$ then $x \le y$.  The transitive closure of $\le$ then gives you a directed graph (with variables as vertices) that represents a preorder (check Wikipedia).  Any strongly connected components in this closure graph represent variables that are all equal.  If you see $x < y$ and  $x = y$ then you have an inconsistency, and if this does not occur then your system is consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find it helpful to think of your problem in terms of equalities and strict inequalities.

In the case of the constraints being equalities or disequalities there is a simple saturation procedure based on transitivity of equality.  Strict inequalities can be represented by directed edges in a graph. You can then compute strongly connected components to reason about dependencies between sets of variables. If you have uninterpreted functions, you can use congruence closure.

I would imagine that the first results date to the 50s or at least the 70s, but I do not have a good reference for you. Recent literature in which these ideas occur is the paper below.

> [An Interpolating Decision Procedure for Transitive Relations with Uninterpreted Functions](http://www.georg.weissenbacher.name/papers/hvc09.pdf), Georg Weissenbacher.